# shell scripting for data arranging

Tags: shell

Data distribution inside my text file (reference.txt) distributed in three sections. Each section demarcated with the line starting with word "ABH".  Each section comprise of many rows. my motive is to convert many rows into single columns from each section. Finally there should be three columns from each sections.

My reference data file

```
       -317       -324       -303       -315       -319       -319       01
       -310       -326       -331       -322       -327       -307       02
       -330       -316       -317       -323       -318       -321       03
       -320       -315       -307       -326       -341       -307       04
       -323       -327       -333       -330       -303       -304       05
       -308       -322
ABH  R  N148  18  1 18  6 44 40.744  980.00    757                          4   
       -304       -300       -308       -307       -324       -329       -325
       -321       -304       -302       -309       -320       -317       -296
       -304       -330       -328       -298       -283       -312       -335
       -330       -324       -312       -298       -301       -321       -326
       -297       -287       -317       -336       -324       -297       -288
       -301       -321
ABH  R  E148  18  1 18  6 44 40.744  980.00    757                          4   
         79         87        117        103         81         92         97
         88         96        103         97         99        105         99
         94         98         95         90         89        107         99
         65        107        143         87         62         99        112
         85         74         97        118        115         95         98
         97         81
```

My final output should be like below

```
-317    -304    79
-324    -300    87
-303    -308    117
-315    -307    103
-319    -324    81
-319    -329    92
-01 -325    97
-310    -321    88
-326    -304    96
-331    -302    103
-322    -309    97
-327    -320    99
-307    -317    105
-02 -296    99
-330    -304    94
-316    -330    98
-317    -328    95
-323    -298    90
-318    -283    89
-321    -312    107
-03 -335    99
-320    -330    65
-315    -324    107
-307    -312    143
-326    -298    87
-341    -301    62
-307    -321    99
-04 -326    112
-323    -297    85
-327    -287    74
-333    -317    97
-330    -336    118
-303    -324    115
-304    -297    95
-05 -288    98
-308    -301    97
-322    -321    81
```

I can arrange the data from one section using shell script (below), but simultaneously how it can applied for other two sections and bring all columns together as shown above. The script for single section I am using is shown below. If anybody can help it will be very helpful. Thank. in advance.

```
for num in $(cat reference.txt)
do
    echo $num >>output.txt
done
```

Comment: Dear Ravinder ji, Thank u for response. The above problem how it can be solved.

Comment: Hello Chittaranjan, could you please fix your samples(may be give little shorter samples with CODE TAGS) and then clarify your logic of getting expected output in your question(not in comments please), once its more clear we will try to help, cheers.

Comment: If you consider only 1st section and delete the rest two section it looks like                                                                                           -317       -324       -303       -315       -319       -319       -01
       -310       -326       -331       -322       -327       -307       -02
       -330       -316       -317       -323       -318       -321       -03
       -320       -315       -307       -326       -341       -307       -04
       -323       -327       -333       -330       -303       -304       -05
       -308       -322
         97         81

Comment: If you use above shell script you  find like the below                                                             -317
-324
-303
-315
-319
-319
-01
-310
-326
-331
-322
-327
-307
-02
-330
-316
-317
-323
-318
-321
-03
-320
-315
-307
-326
-341
-307
-04
-323
-327
-333
-330
-303
-304
-05
-308
-322
97
81                                                                                                                                  So, here my objective is to perform the same operation for other rest two section.

Comment: After directly coying from txt file why its seems like array I dont know, but if you will see the original post you will understand.

Comment: This reads more as "please write a program that does X for me", which is generally not on topic here (corresponding with the close reason "too broad", as it doesn't identify a specific problem encountered over the course of development). A better question is of the form "How do I solve problem Y, which I encountered using the given code to accomplish X"

Comment: We can make logic like this:-                                                                                                      1. run the above script for the rows above the line starting with word 'ABH'                   2. Same execution onl for line below the line staring with word 'ABH'  and above the line staring with 'ABH'. also we can say between two line staring with word 'ABH'.         3. same execution only for line lines below two lines staring with words 'ABH'

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { cnt=1 } /^ABH/ { cnt1=0;cnt++;next;cnt1=0 } { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { cnt1++;map[cnt][cnt1]=$i } } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for(i in map[1]) { for (j=1;j<=cnt;j++) { printf "%s\t",map[j][i] } printf "\n" } }' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
             cnt=1                                              # Initialise a ABH record variable before file processing
           } 
    /^ABH/ { cnt1=0;                                            # When we see "ABH", increment cnt and set cnt1 to 0
             cnt++;
             next;
           } 
           { 
             for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
               cnt1++;                                          # Loop through each spaces delimited field and increment cnt1
               map[cnt][cnt1]=$i                                # Add to a 2 dimensional array with cnt the first index and cnt1 the second. The field value the value.
             } 
           } 
       END {                                                    # Process at the end of the file
             PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";              # Set the array ordering
             for(i in map[1]) { 
                for (j=1;j<=cnt;j++) { 
                   printf "%s\t",map[j][i]                      # Loop through each index of the array printing the values.
                } 
                printf "\n" 
             } 
            }' file
```

Comment: No worries. If the solution meets your needs. Please take the time to upvote and accept the answer.